# Create an anchor element and click and go to it

Tags: jquery

I am trying to go to a specific link with jquery but my code does not do it

None of this works

```
$("<a class='tab-link' href='cnn.com'>cnn</a>").trigger('click');
$("<a class='tab-link' href='cnn.com'>cnn</a>").click();
```

This is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hmkLwme9/7/

The link i want to visit must have the class `tab-link`

How can i do this in jquery?

Comment: `window.location = $('.tab-link').attr('href');`

Comment: And the href has to be valid too. "cnn.com" is not a valid URL

Comment: @Tushar Kindly explain how the code goes to the link.

Comment: @LeQs `$('.tab-link').attr('href')` will give you the `href` attribute value and assigning that URL to `window.location` will redirect to that link.

Comment: @Tushar Kindly make a fiddle

Comment: This works: `$("<a class='tab-link' href='https://jsfiddle.net/'>jsf</a>").on("click",function() {location=this.href}).click();` but is only necessary if you NEED to register a click instead of just a location change https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mp9xbstw/

Comment: @mplungjan thanks,i got this to work `document.getElementById("a_link").click()
` Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create this element and include to DOM. For example:

```
$("<a class='tab-link' href='cnn.com' onClick=\"alert('hello');\">cnn</a>").appendTo("body").trigger('click');
```

Check it on https://jsfiddle.net/hmkLwme9/8/

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: Yes. Check the link on jsfiddle to show it.

Comment: It does not go anywhere. It only triggers the event handler